# Seleccionar objetos dentro de un array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

a ver si me podéis ayudar, recien empiezo con JS...necesito acceder dentro del array y a los objetos "cost" para hacer el coste medio total.

```
var foods = [
    { id: 00, name: 'sausage', from: 'Spain', cost: 160, gluten: false },
    { id: 01, name: 'pepperoni', from: 'Italy', cost: 500, gluten: false },
    { id: 02, name: 'cheese', from: 'Holland', cost: 110, gluten: true },
]
```

Este es el código que realicé, pero únicamente me suma el primer cost (160), no hay manera de que se vaya sumandose para luego hacer el coste medio:

```
  var suma = 0;

function foodsCost (){
    for (var i = 0; i<foods.length; i++){
        var costs = suma += foods[i].cost;      
        return costs;
    }
}

function averageCost () {
    var operator = foodsCost() / 3;
    return operator;
}

averageCost()
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Quita la variable suma de enmedio y ponle costs +=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres:

- Con un bucle
- Recorriendo el array con el método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) (similar al bucle)
- sumando todo con el método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
const foods = [
  { id: 00, name: 'sausage', from: 'Spain', cost: 160, gluten: false },
  { id: 01, name: 'pepperoni', from: 'Italy', cost: 500, gluten: false },
  { id: 02, name: 'cheese', from: 'Holland', cost: 110, gluten: true },
];

//bucle
let suma=0;
for (let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
  suma += foods[i].cost;
}

console.log(suma);

//forEach

suma = 0;
foods.forEach(elem => suma += elem.cost);

console.log(suma);

//reduce: el 0 es el valor inicial del acumulador
suma = foods.reduce((acumulador,elem) => acumulador + elem.cost, 0);

console.log(suma)

//en todos los casos, la media se calcula sencillamente dividiendo la suma
const media= suma / foods.length;

console.log(media);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus opciones, lo veo clarísimo ahora :)

Comment: @Sibavi esta es la respuesta más completa y debería ser marcada como aceptada en lugar de la mía.

Comment: Si, la marco como aceptada, pero en un ppio marqué la tuya al ser lo más parecida a mi planteamiento. @A.Cedano

Comment: @Sibavi esta respuesta es más completa, porque muestra diferentes formas de hacer lo que quieres. Por ejemplo, el uso de `reduce` simplifica mucho las cosas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes sumar los valores dentro de un `forEach` simplemente con esto: `suma += item.cost;`

Además, conviene que uses para el average el total de items del array, no el valor `3` de forma arbitraria, ya que dará un valor erróneo cuando el array no tenga exactamente tres elementos.

El código quedaría así (ha cambiado el nombre de algunas funciones, dándole nombres más descriptivos):

```js
var foods = [{
    id: 00,
    name: 'sausage',
    from: 'Spain',
    cost: 160,
    gluten: false
  },
  {
    id: 01,
    name: 'pepperoni',
    from: 'Italy',
    cost: 500,
    gluten: false
  },
  {
    id: 02,
    name: 'cheese',
    from: 'Holland',
    cost: 110,
    gluten: true
  },
]


function sumCost() {
  var suma = 0;
  foods.forEach(item => {
    suma += item.cost;
  });
  return suma;
}

function averageCost() {
  var operator = sumCost() / foods.length;
  return operator;
}

var avgCost = averageCost();
console.log(avgCost);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

te planteo una posible solución a tu problema en pocas lineas:

```
var foods = [
{ id: 00, name: 'sausage', from: 'Spain', cost: 160, gluten: false },
{ id: 01, name: 'pepperoni', from: 'Italy', cost: 500, gluten: false },
{ id: 02, name: 'cheese', from: 'Holland', cost: 110, gluten: true },
]

let avgCost=0;
foods.forEach(function(element) {
  avgCost += element.cost ;
});
avgCost = avgCost/foods.length;
```

Comment: hola zbotpath, gracias por responder. sin embargo, las respuestas que solo consisten en codigo no se consideran de buena calidad. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir explicacion. Un saludo